# How to test if Doctrine2 DQL query results in a valid result?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

```
function search_event($parish, $genre, $pricerange)
{
    $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT e from Events e WHERE e.parish = :parish AND e.genre = :genre');
    $query->setParameter('parish', $parish);
    $query->setParameter('genre', $genre);
    $result = $query->getResult();     
    return $result;
}
```

In the example above, how do I test if $result is valid?

Comment: Define "valid". Do you mean a collection with 1 or more results?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do to check if there are entities in your returned collection. See [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/doctrine/common/collections/arraycollection.html) for a full list of available methods.

```
// Is result empty?
$result->isEmpty();

// Is result count > 0?
0 < $result->count();
0 < count($result);

// Get the first entitiy
$first = $result->first(); // $first === false if none
```

Answer (score 1):

If `getResult()` returns (i.e. if it doesn't throw an exception), then `$result` is *valid*. (It's always an array of results; which can be empty if there was no result.)

If any error occur (malformed query, connection reset or anything else), ether `createQuery()` or `getResult()` throw an exception.